# Trying to add a button to a iframe HighCharts document, chart variable not found

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/sp7yxLm6/1/) is a working version of what I want to do and have it implemented on part of my site. My problem lies is some of the code is implemented is in this raw html format so inside script tags, I have separated it in my [js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guqLtd6s/) for simplicity but it still does not work, it says chart is not defined. I am setting the chart variable.

I did not write this, but have to use it.

It's the button not adding to the HighCharts Iframe that is not working at the very bottom of the code.

So the line here

```
const chart = new Highcharts.Chart("highcharts-12d5b32d-8c96-4f8d-96a5-a9678ae681ad", options);}}})();
```

Should be making a iframe and giving access to that element via the chart variable where I append to it and add a button.

Does this not work because of the new keyword?

Here is the offending code

```
(function(){ var files = ["https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js","https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js","https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"],loaded = 0; if (typeof window["HighchartsEditor"] === "undefined") {window.HighchartsEditor = {ondone: [cl],hasWrapped: false,hasLoaded: false};include(files[0]);} else {if (window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded) {cl();} else {window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.push(cl);}}function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src){var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {if (scripts[i].hasAttribute("src")) {if ((scripts[i].getAttribute("src") || "").indexOf(src) >= 0 || (scripts[i].getAttribute("src") === "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" && src === "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js")) {return true;}}}return false;}function check() {if (loaded === files.length) {for (var i = 0; i < window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.length; i++) {try {window.HighchartsEditor.ondone[i]();} catch(e) {console.error(e);}}window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded = true;}}function include(script) {function next() {++loaded;if (loaded < files.length) {include(files[loaded]);}check();}if (isScriptAlreadyIncluded(script)) {return next();}var sc=document.createElement("script");sc.src = script;sc.type="text/javascript";sc.onload=function() { next(); };document.head.appendChild(sc);}function each(a, fn){if (typeof a.forEach !== "undefined"){a.forEach(fn);}else{for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){if (fn) {fn(a[i]);}}}}var inc = {},incl=[]; each(document.querySelectorAll("script"), function(t) {inc[t.src.substr(0, t.src.indexOf("?"))] = 1; }); function cl() {if(typeof window["Highcharts"] !== "undefined"){var options={"title":{"text":""},"subtitle":{"text":""},"exporting":{},"chart":{backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2", "type":"column","zoomType":"xy","style":{"fontFamily":"Helvetica","color":"#333","fontSize":"12px","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":"normal"},"borderColor":"#ffffff","inverted":false},"series[0]":{"type":"spline"},

"series":[
{"name":"FY Adj. EBITDA INCL IFRS 16 ($M)","allAreas":true,"colorByPoint":false,"borderColor": "","borderWidth": "0","type":"column","color":"rgba(50,50,50,0.5)", tooltip: {valuePrefix: '$'},"grouping": false
},
{"name":"FY Adj. EBITDA EX IFRS 16 ($M)","borderColor": "","borderWidth": "0", tooltip: {valuePrefix: '$'},"grouping": false
},
{"name":"Adj. EBITDA INCL IFRS 162","marker":{"enabled":true,"symbol":"circle"},"type":"spline","dashStyle":"ShortDash","yAxis":1,"color":"#2db57d", tooltip: {valueSuffix: '%'},
},
{"name":"Adj. EBITDA EX IFRS 16","type":"spline","yAxis":1,"color":"#333333",tooltip: {valueSuffix: '%'},
},

],
"exporting": {

    "buttons": {
      "contextButton": {
        "enabled":false,
      },
    },
  },
"plotOptions":
{
    "series":{"dataLabels":{"style":{"color":"contrast","fontSize":"12px","fontWeight":"bold","textOutline":"null"},"enabled":false}}},
    "data":{"csv":"\"Column 1\";\"FY Adj. EBITDA INCL IFRS 16 ($M)\";\"FY Adj. EBITDA EX IFRS 16 ($M)\";\"Adj. EBITDA INCL IFRS 16\";\"Adj. EBITDA EX IFRS 16\"\n2013;;20.7;;8.0\n2014;;23.8;;8.0\n2015;;34.4;;10.5\n2016;;39.2;;11.1\n2017;;40.6;;11.2\n2018;;36.5;9.9;9.9\n2019;57.5;42;15.3;11.2\n2020;61.0;45.7;15.5;11.6","googleSpreadsheetKey":false,"googleSpreadsheetWorksheet":false},
    "yAxis":[
{"title":{"style":{"fontFamily":"Helvetica","color":"#333333","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":"normal","fontSize":"12px"},"text":"Adjusted EBIDTA Excluding IFRS 16 Impacts ($M)"},"reversed":false,"opposite":false,"tooltipValueFormat":"%","visible":true,"uniqueNames":true,"labels":{"style":{"fontSize":"12px"}}
},
{"opposite":true,"softMax":17,"softMin":0,"minPadding":0,"tooltipValueFormat":"%","ceiling":16,"title":{"style":{"fontFamily":"Helvetica","color":"#333333","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":"normal"},"text":"Adjusted EBIDTA as a % of Net Revenue (%)","reserveSpace":true,"useHTML":false,"x":0},"max":16}
],
"colors":["#b2d235","333333","#2db57d","#bdbdbd"
],
    "xAxis":[{"title":{"style":{"fontFamily":"Helvetica","color":"#333333","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":"normal","fontSize":"12px"}},"labels":{"style":{"fontSize":"12px"}}
}],
    "legend":{"verticalAlign":"bottom","itemStyle":{"fontFamily":"Helvetica","color":"#333333","fontSize":"12px","fontWeight":"bold","fontStyle":"normal","cursor":"pointer"},
},
    "tooltip":{"shared":true,"backgroundColor":"rgba(50,50,50,0.85)", borderColor: 'null', style: {color: 'white', "fontSize":"14px"},valueDecimals:1,
},
"credits":{"enabled":false},"pane":{"background":[]},"responsive":{"rules":[]}};

const chart = new Highcharts.Chart("highcharts-12d5b32d-8c96-4f8d-96a5-a9678ae681ad", options);}}})();

const b = document.createElement('button');
b.textContent = ' ';
b.style.position = 'absolute';
b.style.right = "0px" 
b.style.top = '10px';
b.className = "toggleMe"

 b.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chart.fullscreen.toggle();
    b.classList.toggle("toggleMe");
    b.classList.toggle("toggleMeOff");
}); 

chart.container.appendChild(b);
```

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

Had to move the wrapping function around my code

```
...
const chart = new Highcharts.Chart("highcharts-12d5b32d-8c96-4f8d-96a5-a9678ae681ad", options);

const b = document.createElement('button');
b.textContent = ' ';
b.style.position = 'absolute';
b.style.right = "0px" 
b.style.top = '10px';
b.className = "toggleMe"

 b.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chart.fullscreen.toggle();
    b.classList.toggle("toggleMe");
    b.classList.toggle("toggleMeOff");
}); 

chart.container.appendChild(b);

}}})();
```